# Which extra packages or modules should i remove at compiling time

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm a newbie in compiling the kernel from kernel.org sources.when i compile kernel at my machine which extra or old packages or modules should i remove?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to compile a kernel if you simply want to remove packages that you don't need.

You can simply remove packages by typing `sudo apt-get remove packagename`

You can also remove modules without compiling a kernel by simply doing a `rmmod modulename`

If you want to disable or remove some modules or functionalities from the kernel that you don't use, you can do that when you configure your kernel, then compile the kernel, update your bootloader and reboot.

Basically you'll do:

1. Download kernel source
2. Decompress
3. Make your changes
4. Compile
5. Update bootloader
6. Reboot new kernel

For help on what kind of things to remove, i would say every software that's related to hardware that you don't have, for example:

1. If you don't have bluetooth and don't plan on having in the future,
   remove all bluetooth related software/modules/options;
2. If you have one intel (or other) graphic card, remove other graphic card's
   software;
3. If you don't have TV card's, USB joysticks, etc, etc

If you need help on compiling the kernel from source read the official documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) and [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) or [here](http://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/)

Comment: If this solves your question, don't forget to upvote the answer and mark as correct, as it will help other users with the same question.